# Get cross-device unique ID for Android phone contacts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I need to query the contacts from an Android device for a project I'm working on and I need to save them in a way I can link between the instance in the app to the contact in the phonebook.
I found that the [CONTACT_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID) (which is a reference to [_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID)) of each contact might change between devices, so if I switch to other Android device that ID will not be valid.
A temp solution was using the contact's [SOURCE_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#SOURCE_ID), which is a String that uniquely identifies this row to its source account. The solution was pretty good, because if the contact came from (for example) the Google account, it will stay the exact same ID on every device I'll have. The problem is - **not every contact has a SOURCE_ID**.
It is also possible to query a specific contact using it's data as filters, which may work as a unique ID, such as his phone number, etc... However every piece of data has a flaw. For example: A contact may have multiple phone numbers (which is still ok) and the numbers can be varied (for example: 202-555-0105 is the same as +1-202-555-0105 which is also the same as (202) 555 0105 and also 2025550105).
Edit: Also not every contact has a phone number, so then what?

So after given the problem -
**How can I get a unique ID for the contacts in the Android phonebook so they'll be the same cross-device?**

Note: It's possible on IOS by default (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)) -

> Contacts in different accounts that represent the same person may be automatically linked together. Linked contacts are displayed in OS X and iOS apps as unified contacts. A unified contact is an in-memory, temporary view of the set of linked contacts that are merged into one contact.
>
> By default the Contacts framework returns unified contacts. Each fetched unified contact (CNContact) object has its own unique identifier that is different from any individual contact’s identifier in the set of linked contacts. A refetch of a unified contact should be done with its identifier.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [`LOOKUP_KEY`](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY)

> An opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact if its row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.

To get the contact `LOOKUP_KEY` loop through your contacts, here's an example:

Note: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` is required.

```
val contentUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
val cursor = context?.contentResolver?.query(contentUri, null, null, null, null)
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        val id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
        val name =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY))
        val lookupKey =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY)) 
    }
}
cursor?.close()
```

Here is how you would go about retrieving the contact with the `LOOKUP_KEY`:

```
val lookupKey = "0r1-3C263544104632"
val lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey)
val uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(contentResolver, lookupUri)
val cursor = context?.contentResolver?.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        val id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
        val name =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY))
    }
}
cursor?.close()
}
```

Please note that contacts have to be synchronised in order for the `LOOKUP_KEY` not to be re-generated.

The `LOOKUP_KEY` is guaranteed to be generated for each contact, however, if the account is not set up and not synchronised then the `LOOKUP_KEY` will be re-generated whenever the contact gets modified.

With that in mind, you'll always have a unique `LOOKUP_KEY` if the device is synchronised. The `LOOKUP_KEY` is relying on Google Cloud which may be the same solution that Apple uses.

It will be very unlikely that an Android device will not have a google account since most Android users rely on Google services.

I am afraid this is the best way to have a unique identifier, however, if you'd like, you could hash user phone number combined with other contact details, but this method can not be guaranteed to work as contacts may change. If your users are registered and you'll have their information then you could check on the backend which hash values match your expectation and then work based on your own synchronisation.

If you want to play around, I have created a [sample app](https://github.com/androidsamples/contacts-with-unique-identifier) with the implementation where you can look through your contacts and find the lookup key as well as retrieve the contact with the lookup key.

I would also recommend you to take a look at [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SyncAdapters).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not what I'm looking for. Your answer is the correct way to get the right contactId after it has changed. But my problem is when I'm using more than one Android device (or when switching to a new device). I want the user to be able to switch devices without breaking the app's functionality on the contacts part.

Comment: @lior_13 If the Android device is syncronised with a google account, then when you switch devices and re-synchronise you'll be able to search for the contact with the same LOOKUP_KEY cross-device. So as long as the account and devices a synchronised.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. So if the synchronisation is off, or the new device is not yet synced with the account, and the contact details has changed, the LOOKUP_KEY on the new device will not be able to link to the right contact? If so, what can I do to be 100% certain I am talking about the same contact no matter what?

Comment: Yes, the `LOOKUP_KEY` is guaranteed to be generated for each contact, however if the account is not synchronised then the `LOOKUP_KEY` will change whenever the contact gets modified. With that in mind, you'll always have a unique `LOOKUP_KEY` if the device is synchronised. The `LOOKUP_KEY` is relying on Google Cloud which may be the same solution that Apple uses. It will be very unlikely that an Android will not have a google account and not be synchronised. I've updated the answer with more information.