# Is there a unique identifier for Android phone contacts?

Tags: android, xamarin, contacts

I have an app that reads the contact details of the phone. This code returns 744 as the id of a particular contact's row when accessed through Email.ContentUri.

```
                            var uriEmail = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri;
                            string[] projectionEmail = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoUri, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Address };
                            var cursorEmail = this.Activity.ContentResolver.Query(uriEmail, projectionEmail, null, null, null);

                            // var contactList = new List<string>();
                            contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

                            if (cursorEmail.MoveToFirst())
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    //contactList.Add(cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2])));
                                    contacts.Add(new Contact()
                                    {
                                        Id = cursorEmail.GetInt(cursorEmail.GetColumnIndex(projectionEmail[0])),
                                        Name = cursorEmail.GetString(cursorEmail.GetColumnIndex(projectionEmail[1])),
                                        Photo = cursorEmail.GetString(cursorEmail.GetColumnIndex(projectionEmail[2])),
                                        Email = cursorEmail.GetString(cursorEmail.GetColumnIndex(projectionEmail[3])),
                                    });
                                }
                                while (cursorEmail.MoveToNext());
                            }

                            ListView listEmail = v.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewSelect);

                            listEmail.Adapter = new ContactAdapter(v.Context, contacts);
                            listEmail.ItemClick += OnClientListClick;
```

This code returns 752 as the id of the same contact when accessed through StructuredPostal.ContentUri.

```
                        var uriAddress = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentUri;
                        string[] projectionAddress = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoUri, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Street, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Postcode };
                        var cursorAddress = this.Activity.ContentResolver.Query(uriAddress, projectionAddress, null, null, null);

                        // var contactList = new List<string>();
                        properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();

                        if (cursorAddress.MoveToFirst())
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                int n = cursorAddress.GetInt(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[0]));
                                string str = cursorAddress.GetString(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[1]));
                                if (n == nId)
                                {
                                    //contactList.Add(cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2])));
                                    properties.Add(new Property()
                                    {
                                        Id = cursorAddress.GetInt(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[0])),
                                        Name = cursorAddress.GetString(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[1])),
                                        Photo = cursorAddress.GetString(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[2])),
                                        Street = cursorAddress.GetString(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[3])),
                                        Postcode = cursorAddress.GetString(cursorAddress.GetColumnIndex(projectionAddress[4])),
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            while (cursorAddress.MoveToNext());
                        }

                        ListView listAddress = v.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewSelect);

                        listAddress.Adapter = new PropertyAdapter(v.Context, properties);
                        listAddress.ItemClick += OnPropertyListClick;
```

Is there a unique identifier that's allocated to the contact in the Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna a unique id, you could use CONTACT_ID which is a reference to _ID of each contact.

- CONTACT_ID:
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID
- _ID：https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns#_ID

If you want to use the unique id cross device, you could try to use the LOOKUP_KEY.

- LOOKUP_KEY:
  https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY

For more code details, you could check the link below. [Get cross-device unique ID for Android phone contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58118556/get-cross-device-unique-id-for-android-phone-contacts)

Comment: Thank you Wendy. I'll start there.